# Managing static/images in Django with AppEngine

Tags: django, image, google-app-engine, static

I am trying to add an image to my simple google app engine code, but it doesn't work if I follow the tutorial. It works if my image is in my app directory, but not when I move it to static.

When I am using it in plain html like:

```
<img src="../static/myimage.jpg"></img>
```

or

[image]

and many other variations, the image just does not show (it shows when it is outside of static dir). When I am doing it as in the tutorial, defining STATIC_URL in my settings file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And adding this lines (or variations like "/my_image.jpg" and so on)

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my-app/myimage.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

causes server error (500). I am using django 1.3

Here is the directory structure:

```
my-app
  \static
       myimage.jpg
  \templates
       base.html
       # and other html files
  \urls.py, settings.py #and other .py files
```

App.yaml:

```
 -url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
```

setting.py:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

urls.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: can u please post your static folder structure??

Comment: it's very simple. my_app directory contains two subdirectories static and templates

Comment: try `src="{{ STATIC_URL }}myimage.jpg">`

Comment: did not work even after I removed the entire line. Putting {% load staticfiles %} into a file crashes the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you set STATIC_ROOT to?

Generally though, using GAE's static file handlers in app.yaml will give you better caching and probably lower cost than serving the images with django's staticfiles.

Comment: I've added definitions from app.yaml file to this question. Something wrong with it?

Comment: yes, I did not need load staticfiles, it works fine without it